# Checking if a date falls within an interval in a dataset in long format

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have two datasets with `tests` (dates and results - long format) and `meds` (medication dates) for a number of patients. There are two tests per patients, on two separate dates.

```r
(tests <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), test_date = structure(c(10957, 
10963, 11001, 11035, 11091, 11230), class = "Date"), test_result = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame"))

#>   id  test_date test_result
#> 1  1 2000-01-01           1
#> 2  1 2000-01-07           1
#> 3  2 2000-02-14           0
#> 4  2 2000-03-19           1
#> 5  3 2000-05-14           0
#> 6  3 2000-09-30           0

(meds <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), med_date = structure(c(10959, 
10956, NA), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"))

#>   id   med_date
#> 1  1 2000-01-03
#> 2  2 1999-12-31
#> 3  3       <NA>
```

I'm trying to create a new column in `tests` that specifies whether that patient received the medication within the interval between the two test dates.

Intended output:

```r
#>   id  test_date test_result   received_med_within
#> 1  1 2000-01-01           1   TRUE
#> 2  1 2000-01-07           1   TRUE
#> 3  2 2000-02-14           0   FALSE
#> 4  2 2000-03-19           1   FALSE
#> 5  3 2000-05-14           0   FALSE
#> 6  3 2000-09-30           0   FALSE
```

I thought I could tackle this by

1. pivotting `tests` wider,
2. `left_join`ing `meds` to it,
3. using `if_else(med_date %within% interval(test_date_1, test_date_2), TRUE, FALSE)`
4. pivotting it longer again

However this is rather convoluted and as the real datasets contain many more columns, pivotting might get a bit tricky.

Is there a cleaner way to check if a date falls between two dates in a long dataset?

Comment: I'm sure there is a reason why the answer to this is no but if the real dataset has more columns but you only need the dates, can't you just subset it and pivot only the ID and date columns?

Comment: Good question - it's that I'm doing this for a later plot, for which I'll also need some other columns (which are also pivot-sensitive...)

Comment: Hmmm... it is hard to suggest a solution without knowing the future constraints. My inclination would generally be to do it exactly as you have set out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
library(dplyr)

tests %>%
  left_join(meds) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(received_med_within = between(med_date, test_date[1], test_date[2])) %>% 
  tidyr::replace_na(list(received_med_within = FALSE)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-4)

# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   id [3]
# id test_date  test_result received_med_within
# <dbl> <date>           <dbl> <lgl>              
# 1     1 2000-01-01           1 TRUE               
# 2     1 2000-01-07           1 TRUE               
# 3     2 2000-02-14           0 FALSE              
# 4     2 2000-03-19           1 FALSE              
# 5     3 2000-05-14           0 FALSE              
# 6     3 2000-09-30           0 FALSE
```

Comment: Of course - `test_date[1]` and `test_date[2]` or even `min(test_date)` and `max(test_date)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `match`.

```
tests <- tests[order(tests$id, tests$test_date),] #In case its not ordered

i <- match(tests$id[c(TRUE, FALSE)], meds$id)
cbind(tests, received_med_within =
       rep(tests$test_date[c(TRUE, FALSE)] < meds$med_date[i] &
              meds$med_date[i] < tests$test_date[c(FALSE, TRUE)], each = 2))
#  id  test_date test_result received_med_within
#1  1 2000-01-01           1                TRUE
#2  1 2000-01-07           1                TRUE
#3  2 2000-02-14           0               FALSE
#4  2 2000-03-19           1               FALSE
#5  3 2000-05-14           0                  NA
#6  3 2000-09-30           0                  NA
```